# Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) for push notifications on iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Amazon Web Services have an [SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) which supports the [Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/).

Does this mean it would be possible to use SNS to send push notifications to a running iOS app? So for example you could make an real-time instant messaging app.

Is this right, or have I misunderstood what SNS does? It just seems to me that you would need to open a connection/socket in order to recieve push notifications from your server. How does the SDK actually work?

**Update:**

I've since asked this question on the AWS Mobile Development Forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81089&tstart=0

Apparently there is an article coming out (probably here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/iOS) shortly to explain everything.

**Update 2**
The article: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/9156883257507082

Comment: If you are targeting Apple's appstore, remember that the App Store Guidelines state: _5.1 Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be
rejected_

Comment: Would that also be the case if you were using it just to power instant messaging whilst the app was running? Or would would you have to send an APNs to say there's a new message, go fetch (designed such that it doesn't show a notification if not running)?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you a good answer -- I just wanted to remind that you might have troubles when submitting the app. It's just a comment to promote further research :]

Comment: Is SNS maybe similar to UrbanAirship - in the sense that they use Apple's APNS underneath, but wrap it in a custom API?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) "Local notifications and push notifications are ways for an application that isn’t running in the foreground to let its users know it has information for them.".

So, technically speaking, any data, including notifications, received when the application is running in the foreground are not "Push Notifications" and can't be a reason for rejecting the application. They're simply data being consumed that way or the other by the application.

In this specific case you are not asking about Push Notifications per Apple's documentation, rather about a technology used to deliver data to the application when the application is running and user is interacting with it. It happens that the name Amazon SNS is similar to Push Notification.

In any case Apple wouldn't be able to see what is the technology behind delivering data to your application, whether it is Amazon SNS or anything else. All they can see is that the application may have some additional ports open when it's running, and that of course would be absolutely legal. In fact, many applications communicate with their back-end servers using [sockets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) (not HTTP requests), and that is the same technology as used by Apple to deliver their Push Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html), they in turn uses the APNS method and provide a much simpler frontend for Apple, Android and Kindle. A realtime instant messaging app could be considered as workable since by using the Amazon SNS platform, you could even consider the application to be available for all.

I mean by utilizing the Amazon SNS, the communication could be done between iOS and Android devices and to kindle also provided the applications are written accordingly. Though the Amazon documents do not provide a comprehensive example, there are bits and pieces. Also there is an upcoming event on the Aug 29 which could be seen from the [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) page.